# Strict inequality linked with sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

Suppose a sequence $a_{n}$ is defined in following way: $a_{1}=1, a_{n}=a_{1}a_{2}a_{3}…a_{n-1}+1, n \geq 2$. Prove, that for every natural number $m$ an inequality holds $\frac{1}{a_{1}}+\frac{1}{a_{2}}+…+\frac{1}{a_{m}} < 2$.

I tried obtaining $a_{n}$ in a closed form, but I didn’t succeed. Had a thought to prove it inductively, but it fails.The only useful fact I managed to find is the identity $a_{n}=a_{n-1}^2-a_{n-1}+1$ for $n >=  3$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: you have find this 
$$a_{n}=a^2_{n-1}-a_{n-1}+1$$
then
$$a_{n}-1=a_{n-1}(a_{n-1}-1)\Longrightarrow\dfrac{1}{a_{n}-1}=\dfrac{1}{a_{n-1}-1}-\dfrac{1}{a_{n-1}}$$
so
$$\dfrac{1}{a_{n-1}}=\dfrac{1}{a_{n-1}-1}-\dfrac{1}{a_{n}-1}$$
then following you can solve your problem?